# Getting the key of the latest datetime in a dictionary where key=string and value=datetime object

Tags: python, dictionary, datetime

I have a dictionary

```
from datetime import datetime

time_delta_dict = {'A': datetime.datetime(year=2020, month=6, day=1, hour=11, minute=0), 
                   'B': datetime.datetime(year=2020, month=6, day=1, hour=21, minute=0), 
                   'C': datetime.datetime(year=2020, month=6, day=1, hour=18, minute=0), 
                   'D': datetime.datetime(year=2020, month=6, day=1, hour=15, minute=0)}
```

How can I return the key with the latest date and time? In my example, the latest would be key 'B'. 
I have tried getting the maximum number of hours in each datetime object but it only works when everything else is constant.

When months and days vary randomly, its a different story. I think I am missing out some of datetime module functionality. How can I proceed with this?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `max()` function with a `key` argument:

```
import datetime

time_delta_dict = {'A': datetime.datetime(year=2020, month=6, day=1, hour=11, minute=0),
                   'B': datetime.datetime(year=2020, month=6, day=1, hour=21, minute=0),
                   'C': datetime.datetime(year=2020, month=6, day=1, hour=18, minute=0),
                   'D': datetime.datetime(year=2020, month=6, day=1, hour=15, minute=0)}

key_max, value_max = max(time_delta_dict.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])
print(key_max)
```

Output:

```
B
```

Comment: Hi Terry! Thanks a  lot . I thought  there is something more in the datetime module I have not used. :D :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) module for this

```
from datetime import datetime

time_delta_dict = {'A': datetime(year=2020, month=6, day=1, hour=11, minute=0), 
                   'B': datetime(year=2020, month=6, day=1, hour=21, minute=0), 
                   'C': datetime(year=2020, month=6, day=1, hour=18, minute=0), 
                   'D': datetime(year=2020, month=6, day=1, hour=15, minute=0)} 

key, date =  max(time_delta_dict.items(), key = lambda x: x[1])
print(key)
```

Output : 
B

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

```
from datetime import datetime

time_delta_dict = {'A': datetime(year=2020, month=6, day=1, hour=11, minute=0), 
                   'B': datetime(year=2020, month=6, day=1, hour=21, minute=0), 
                   'C': datetime(year=2020, month=6, day=1, hour=18, minute=0), 
                   'D': datetime(year=2020, month=6, day=1, hour=15, minute=0)}

max = max([time_delta_dict[i] for i in time_delta_dict])

v = [k for k in time_delta_dict if time_delta_dict[k] == max]
print(v[0])
```